# Macro to find a value in one column and a value in another column to return the values in different columns when both the previous values are TRUE

Tags: macros, comparison

I have a worksheet that I need to pull in data from another file.  I need a Macro to take the values in Column A and Column D respectively in each row of the active worksheet and compare the those values with values in the other file, Columns A and F respectively.  If a match is found somewhere within the rows of this worksheet, then I want it to take the values within Column B and C and place them into Column B and C of the first worksheet.  I am new to building macros and this one just has me stumped on how to get what I need.  Can anyone help?

Example of Worksheets:

First Worksheet

[image]

Second Worksheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I combined the top assembly and the comp item and did a VLOOKUP for both of the columns.  It's sloppy for it works...

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Sheets("Potential Issues").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unique Top Assembly Comp Item Number"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NHA Item"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NHA User Item Type"
With ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
   If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
       With .Columns(2)
           .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]&RC[3]"
       End With
   End If
End With
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
With ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        With .Columns(3)
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(C[-1],'B2.0 Buys Exploded BOM'!C2:C4,2,0)"
        End With
    End If
End With
With ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        With .Columns(4)
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(C[-2],'B2.0 Buys Exploded BOM'!C2:C4,3,0)"
        End With
    End If
End With
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 21
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 24
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 15
Range("B:B,G:H").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A1").Select
```